# dynamic width for read only textbox with css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a read only text-box, its value is coming from database.. I am not sure about text length..client wants that text-box to be dynamic based on content.

Is there any way to do with pure css??

Thanks in advance

```html
<div class="form-item ">
<label class="control-label">Task Name</label>

<input class="form-control form-text"  readonly="readonly" type="text"
value="text-box width should change based on my length">
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't do this with a text input and CSS.

But if it's read-only, why use a text input? Why not create a span and style it to *look* like a text input?

Comment: Actually the site is created by drupal team ..so I cant change html elements ..so jquery is the only option now?